# Error are coming when trying to open chrome using selenium first time

Tags: selenium

Exception thread "main" org.opens.selenium.WebDriverException:unknown error :chrome failed to start

Comment: Please add your code and some more information.

Comment: I guess you are not adding Chromedriver path in code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not adding [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) path in code, first download the Chromedriver and add it like this

```
public class Test1
{
public static void main(string[] args)
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://batc‌​h235//‌​chromedriver‌.exe");
C‌​hromeDrive‌​r driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
}
}
```

Add your `chromedriver` path in place of `E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe`

Comment: c‌​hromosomes.exe?? Means it should be Sysyem.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://batch235//c‌​hromodriver.exe");

Comment: package stevejobs;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class Test1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://batch235//chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
  driver.close();
  
 }

}